# Is it safe to flash dm-verity zip on S8 EXYNOS G905F?

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode, samsung-galaxy-s-8

Is it safe to flash the dm-verity zip?

I am asking due to, seeing/reading some cases when attempting to flash a ROM the phone will get to the ERASING stage, show dm-verity error, then reboot, and it will do that endlessly.

I have tried flashing TWRP but every time, my phone gets stuck in a bootloop no matter how I start TWRP and regardless of whether I wipe and format the data or not.

NOTE: The dm-verity zip was never flashed on any TWRP recovery installation attempt. Each time I flashed using a stock ROM.

```
1. Flash TWRP.
2. See if the phone can still boot into system.
    If boots into system
        3a. Attempt to confirm TWRP availability by booting into recovery and system OS various ways to ensure it is always available.
            If TWRP is not installed (eg stock recovery appears)
                If can boot into system successfully
                    4a. Goto 1.
                If boot loops
                    4a. Goto 3b.
            If TWRP in successful installed (TWRP always boots up)
                5. Undefined (possibly attempt to install Magisk or SuperSU? depends which one will be safer).
    If boot loops
        3b. Reflash stock ROM.
        4b. Boot into it and wait for initial setup screen to appear.
        5. Goto 1.
```

I am running Android 8.0, XSA carrier Samsung Galaxy S8 G950F (was very difficult to find a stock ROM for this model).

I DO NOT want to end up being unable to reflash the STOCK ROM should anything go wrong during attempting to root.
If I am unable to manually root, will a [Custom ROM](https://www.goandroid.co.in/best-custom-roms-for-samsung-galaxy-s8-and-galaxy-s8-plus/89093/)
offer root built-in to the ROM itself? And if so, if I end up flashing a ROM incorrectly will I still be able to flash the stock ROM and try again?